# Using Stencil.js Router in Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

I have a Stencil.js application that I created with some routes inside using the `@stencil/router` module. I am now attempting to place the components of this application inside of a larger Angular application, but the routing doesn't seem to work. For example, I navigate to my Angular component that renders the Stencil.js Web Component, which is the Stencil.js application's root that sets up the routes. Then, a button in the Web Component has a `stencil-route-link` to route to a different component inside the Stencil.js application. Instead of redirecting the Stencil.js application to the appropriate component, the navigation bar is replaced and the page is not found.

Is there any way to use a different router module inside of Angular without it conflicting with the Angular router itself? If so, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have put `schemas: CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in your Angular module, right?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? and if you did, could you provide some details how you did it?